Como puedo sumar 2 variables con valor numérico en bash?
quiero saber como puedo sumar 2 variables con valor numérico en bash. Este es mi código:
#!/bin/bash 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             echo "Suma de 2 numeros:"                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
numero1= $1                                                                                                             
numero2= $2                                                                                                             
suma=`expr $numero1 +$numero2`                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
echo "Suma: $suma"

Lo he probado y este es el error que muestra:
./Parametros.sh 1 2                                                                                            
Suma de 2 numeros:                                                                                                      
./Parametros.sh: línea 5: 1: orden no encontrada                                                                        
./Parametros.sh: línea 6: 2: orden no encontrada                                                                        
expr: syntax error: missing argument after «+»                                                                          
Suma:


No hace falta que uses una expresión, puedes sumarlos directamente, por ejemplo:
#!/bin/bash

num1=$1
num2=$2

suma=$(($num1 + $num2))

echo $suma

Tampoco hace falta que captures los valores de los argumentos en variables, podrías usarlos directamente:
#!/bin/bash

suma=$(( $1 + $2 ))

echo $suma

Si quieres usar una expresión, deja un espacio entre el signo + y el segundo operando:
#!/bin/bash

num1=$1
num2=$2

suma=`expr $num1 + $num2`

echo $suma

En todos los casos, produce un resultado como:
jcastillo@devUbuntu:~$ ./sumar.sh 10 15
25


Muchas gracias, realmente tus respuestas me han ayudado y ahora tengo más ideas de como hacerlo.
